Agregar una Columna a un Resultado de un Loop en R
Necesito agregar una columna a un resultado de un loop y luego llevar el resultado a un data frame, siendo el loop el resultado de una función.
Por ejemplo:
interes_simple <- function(capital, tasa, tiempo){
     return(capital*(1+(tasa*tiempo)))
} 

el cual me entrega como resultado los valores:
105, 110, 115, 120, 125
si uso el loop
for (i in 1:5) {
  print(interes_simple(capital, tasa, i))
}

. A esto me gustaría que agregue una variable con el valor de i para cada caso, y luego pasar el resultado a un dataframe.
Gracias

En tu caso, la función que has construido es perfectamente vectorizable, por lo que puede aplicarse directamente a un vector de días, no es necesario pasar por un loop:
capital <- 100
tasa <- 3
df <- data.frame(dias=1:5)
df$is <- interes_simple(capital, tasa, df$dias)

  dias   is
1    1  400
2    2  700
3    3 1000
4    4 1300
5    5 1600

Aqui lo que hacemos es generar un data.frame con el número de días y sobre el mismo aplicamos la función pasandole df$dias como parámetro, esto se logra por que todas las operaciones aritméticas son vectorizables en R.
Por otro lado, si quieres de todas formas usar un loop, puedes hacerlo, pero mi recomendación es trabajar con una lista para llenar los datos y luego conbertirla fuera del loop. Usar rutinas como rbind dentro de un ciclo suele ser una mala práctica ya que por cada iteración se va haciendo una copia completa del data.frame lo que en algunos escenarios, no en el tuyo, puede ser problemático. La idea sería algo así:
capital <- 100
tasa <- 3
df <- data.frame(dias=1:5)
lista <- list()  
for (dias in df$dias) {
  lista[[dias]] <- (interes_simple(capital, tasa, dias))
}    
df$is <- do.call(rbind, lista)

Por último, un comentario, la formula del calculo de renta por medio del interes simple, si no me equivoco, es algo así: capital * ((tasa/100) / dias) siempre que tasa sea en este caso una tasa diaria.

Cuando realices la iteración, puedes agregar los valores que necesitas, primeramente crea un vector para almacenar la información:
resultado <- data.frame(tiempo = integer(), interes = numeric())

ahora iteras y almacenas la información en el dataframe, para posteriormente usarla
for (i in 1:5) {
   #print(interes_simple(capital, tasa, i))
   interes_capital = interes_simple(capital, tasa, i)
   resultado <- rbind(resultado, data.frame(i, interes_capital = interes_capital))
}

print(resulado)

Donde tendrías como salida:
 i       interes_capital
 1             105
 2             110
 3             115
 4             120
 5             125

